# Keep default behavior when new trigger is inserted SQL

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have contraints on a table. When I try to insert something there which doesn't have the correct data, I get an error in the console saying that this and that IC was violated.

```
ERROR:  null value in column "column" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (0, null, null, null, null).
```

Now if I add a this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_function()
  RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$
    BEGIN
     raise notice 'test';
     return null;
    END;
  $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


create trigger test_trigger
  before update or insert
  on tablename
  for each row
  execute procedure trigger_function();
```

And execute the same thing as before I instead get this:

```
NOTICE:  test
INSERT 0 0
```

I know that this trigger isn't really useful but I'm still learning how they work.

Is it possible to keep the previous error messages, and add whatever I did in the trigger_function after it? Why does it replace all the default messages?

Comment: If you want to see errors change it to `AFTER` Trigger

Comment: That makes some sense, but shouldn't the other things still run afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)

> Row-level triggers fired BEFORE can **return null** to signal the trigger manager **to skip the rest of the operation** for this row (i.e., subsequent triggers are not fired, and the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE does not occur for this row)

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Because your trigger returns `NULL` the `insert` is never actually done and thus no constraint can be violated.

[The output](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.152.7) in the psql console

```
INSERT 0 0
```

tells you that no rows have been inserted. The second value is the number of rows inserted.

---

If you want a trigger that "does nothing", you need to use `return new`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_function()
  RETURNS trigger 
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  raise notice 'test';
  return new; --<< here
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Amazing. That was it! Thank you